# unexpected result iterating over a boost::python vector_indexing_suite

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, stdvector

I have wrapped successfully a class named Composite.
This class has the following method:

```
std::vector<Composite*> Composite::getChildren();
```

I tried to wrap the returned std::vector using the vector_indexing_suite, in this way:
[snippet]

```
typedef std::vector<Composite*> CompositeArray;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(composite)
{   
    class_<CompositeArray>("CompositeArray")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<CompositeArray, true>());


    class_<Composite>("Composite", init<>())
        ... more wrapper
        .def("getChildren", &Composite::getChildren)
        ... more wrapper
        ;
}
```

Now everything seem working correctly and when I call the getChildren() method from python it returns correctly a wrapped CompositeArray. I can do, for example:

```
from composite import Composite
myComp = Composite()

myComp.addChild('childA')
myComp.addChild('childB')

len(myComp.getChildren())  #returns 2
myComp.getChildren()[0] # returns the first child of type Composite
```

But when I try to iterate over the CompositeArray, like in this way:

```
for child in myComp.getChildren():
    # do something with child...
```

I got this error message:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class Composite * __ptr64
```

which doesn't make any sense to me, considering that access by index worked perfectly!
I'm stuck on this... do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `class Composite * __ptr64` looks like iterator returns pure pointer and `boost::python` tries to copy that as Python wrapped object.
I guess you did not provide somthing like `class_<Composite*>()`.
Can you show return type of `Composite::iterator::operator*()`?

Comment: Thanks elmo, but shouldn't a pointer to a Composite being handled by class_<Composite>? I've never seen wrapping a pointer, only the type... so I'm even more confuse now.
And what do you mean for Composite::iterator::operator*(), Composite itself it is just a normal class and does not have iterator...

Comment: Oh, I missed that container is named `CompositeArray` and inherits from `std::vector`. In that case the return value of `CompositeArray::iterator::operator*()` will be pointer. I am quite surprised that compiles, because if you try to define a function `Composite * some_function()` with `.def("some_function", &some_function)` it will give you an error stating that you need to provide return policy. I think in the above code we need to do the same.

Comment: That's right elmo, I have other methods wrapped that return pointers and indeed I had to specify a return policy for them.

So the question maybe now: how can I specify the return policy for the wrapped std::vector<Composite*> (or CompositeArray, if you prefer)??

Comment: I would probably copy [provided implementation for vector_indexing_suite](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp) and poke around that. Or just inherit from that and override `get_item` as a first try.

Comment: The really weird thing is that the access by index works without problems!

Comment: Ok, then my next step would be to run that under debugger and stop on that throw and see the stack trace to try to figure out how we get there. Does `for x in X` actually use `get_item` in that case.
Though I am still confused why this works for indices...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class_<Composite, Composite*>("Composite", init<>())
```

Instead of

```
class_<Composite>("Composite", init<>())
```